# Replace values dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I want to replace some values in my dataframe that meets a condition.
I tried to write the code but does not seem working

```
dfa = df.copy()

for value in df['Clean Company Name']:
    if value=="NaN":
        dfa['Clean Company Name'].replace(df['Company Name'])


dfa.head()
```

[image]

As you can see, the NaN values are not replaced by the 'Company Name'

How do I achieve that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need replace `NaN` values need functions [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Clean Company Name'].combine_first(df['Company Name'])
```

Or:

```
df['Clean Company Name'].fillna(df['Company Name'])
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company Name':['s','d','f'], 'Clean Company Name': [np.nan, 'r', 't']})
print (df)
  Clean Company Name Company Name
0                NaN            s
1                  r            d
2                  t            f

#if need check NaNs
print (df['Clean Company Name'].isnull())
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: Clean Company Name, dtype: bool


df['Clean Company Name'] = df['Clean Company Name'].combine_first(df['Company Name'])
print (df)
  Clean Company Name Company Name
0                  s            s
1                  r            d
2                  t            f
```

More about [missing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html).

EDIT:

For replace data by condition is possible use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `boolean mask`:

```
print (df['Company Name'] == 'd')
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: Company Name, dtype: bool

df.loc[df['Company Name'] == 'd', 'Clean Company Name'] = 'sss'
print (df)
  Clean Company Name Company Name
0                NaN            s
1                sss            d
2                  t            f
```

Comment: Apparently it does not even recognize if value=="NaN". It never falls in that case

Comment: for check NaNs use [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html)

Comment: Thanks, I still have on doubt: how do I iterate trought the dataframe and change entries in some specific row according to its value?
I want to be able to check the value (if statement logic) and take actions accordingly

Comment: @Alex - I add another sample, please check it.